# custom order rules for array of object

Tags: javascript, lodash

how do I sort by rules on an array of object. As I know unlike object, by using array the order of item is fixed

```
[{name: 'james', name: 'alice', name: 'sam'}]
```

so if I map print the list above, the order will be james, alice sam. What if I want to order above item by a set of rules?

rules:

1. james, alice, sam (default)
2. alice, sam, james
3. sam, james, alice

is there any helper like lodash can accomplish this? basically I need have a function

```
function sortByRules(rules) { //do something with the array }
```

Comment: What do you mean by rules. What would you need to pass on those rules?

Comment: it could be 3 array like ['james', 'alice', 'sam'] or ['alice', 'sam', 'james'] or ['sam', 'james', 'alice']

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `sort` as `data.sort((a, b) => rule.indexOf(a.name) - rule.indexOf(b.name));`. Here `rule` is any one of the rules that you want to sort array with.

In case you have more items into `data` which are not included in `rule` then it will appear at the beginning of the result with `sortByRules` function.

If you want that to appear in last then use `sortByRules2`.

Try it below.

```js
var data = [
  { name: 'james' },
  { name: 'alice' },
  { name: 'sam' },
  { name: 'bob' }
];

var rules = [
  ['james', 'alice', 'sam'],
  ['alice', 'sam', 'james'], 
  ['sam', 'james', 'alice']
];

// names which are not included in rule will appear first.
function sortByRules(rule) { 
  data.sort((a, b) => rule.indexOf(a.name) - rule.indexOf(b.name));
  console.log(data);
}

// names which are not included in rule will appear last.
function sortByRules2(rule) {
  data.sort((a, b) => {
    let aIndex = rule.indexOf(a.name);
    let bIndex = rule.indexOf(b.name);
    aIndex = aIndex === -1 ? data.length : aIndex;
    bIndex = bIndex === -1 ? data.length : bIndex;
    return aIndex - bIndex
  });
  console.log(data);
}

sortByRules(rules[1]);
sortByRules2(rules[1]);
```

Comment: will this work if I have more item in the array?

Answer (score 0):

```
var data = [{
    name: 'james'
  },
  {
    name: 'alice'
  }, {
    name: 'sam'
  }
];

console.log(data.sort((a,b) => {
    if(a.name === 'alice'){
  return -1;
  } else {
  return 1;
  }
}));
```

Basically, when you compare items, you return 1 to move a down, -1 to move b up, or 0 to not move any thing.

Comment: I need to pass in a set of rules, but === 'alice' will solve the problem, I don't seem to understand the problem

Comment: What would a rule you want to program for look like?

Comment: it could be 3 array like ['james', 'alice', 'sam'] or ['alice', 'sam', 'james'] or ['sam', 'james', 'alice']

Comment: Ok, and what are you trying to do?  Are you trying to move certain names up or certain names down?

Answer (score 0):

First I think you have the array malformed and it should be

```js
[{name: 'james'}, {name: 'alice'}, {name: 'sam'}]
```

instead of

```js
[{name: 'james', name: 'alice', name: 'sam'}]
```

Now we need to understand why you mean by rules, what for what I've red you want to pass an array of people like so `['james', 'alice']` and get those values first, well then you can do something like this:

```js
const people = [
  { name: 'james' },
  { name: 'alice' },
  { name: 'sam' },
  { name: 'will' },
];

const sortByRules = (arr, rules = []) => {
  const inRules = arr.filter((person) => rules.includes(person.name));

  inRules.sort((a, b) => rules.indexOf(a.name) - rules.indexOf(b.name));

  return [...inRules, ...arr.filter((person) => !rules.includes(person.name))];
};

console.log(sortByRules(people, ['alice', 'sam', 'james']));
```